# не могу дать wrapper-у 100% высоту помогите

Tags: html, css

во первых контент над footer-ом

и wrapper не принимает высоту в 100% вот и код

```css
   



 `*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
         color: #666;
         opacity: 1;
    }
    *:-moz-placeholder {
      color: #666;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    *::-moz-placeholder {
      color: #666;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    *:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #666;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    body input:focus:required:invalid,
    body textarea:focus:required:invalid {
    
    }
    body input:required:valid,
    body textarea:required:valid {
    
    }
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "RobotoRegular", sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    
    }
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      min-width: 970px;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto!important;
    }
    .wrapper:after {
      content: '';
      height: 80px;
      display: block;
    }
    /*============================ШАПКА============================*/
    .header {
      min-width: 970px;
      height: 70px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    .menu_li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
      color: white;
      line-height: 22px;
    }
    /*============================ФАМИЛИЯ============================*/
    .surname {
      font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
      font-size: 28px;
    
    }
    /*============================СЛЕДУИШИЙ============================*/
    .next {
      font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC" ,sans-serif;
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      height: 70px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      background: #bdc3c7;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
    }
    .menu_right {
      padding: 5px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      float: right;
      font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
      color: white;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    .menu_right:hover {
      color: #2F4153;
    }
    /*===========================шапка конец=============================*/
    /*==========================about me================*/
    
    /*задний фон желтый*/
    .content-section {
      position:relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    
    }
    .content-section .bg-color{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .bg-color {
      background-color: #FDBD12;
      height: 667px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url(../img/edgebottom.png);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-position: bottom;
    
    }
    /*задний фон желтый конец*/
    .bio-content {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1664px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
    
    }
    .content-section h2 {
      font-size: 4em;
    }
    .text-group {
      position: absolute;
      left: 180px;
      top: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .title  {
      font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
      font-weight: bolder;
      width: 450px;
      height: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      left: -50px;
      top: -90px;
      padding:0;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    #family td {
      left: 170px;
      top: 60px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-right: 12px;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    #family td:first-child {
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 1;
      padding-top: 3px;
      text-align: right;
    
    }
    /*задний фон*/
    .about-rh {
      background-image: url(../img/ab.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 433px;
      height: 531px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 580px;
      top: 130px;
    
    }
    .about-timeline {
      background-image: url(../img/coordinates.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 90px;
      height: 401px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 300px;
      top: 130px;
    }
    /*задний фон конец*/
    /*.about-rh {
      position: relative;
      width:100%;
      height: 580px;
      background-color: #FDBD12;
      background-image:url(../img/edgebottom.png),url(../img/ab.jpg),url(../img/coordinates.jpg);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1300px 100px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    */
    .about-year {
      position: absolute;
      right: 240px;
      top: 25px;
    }
    .about-year span {
      color: white;
    }
    .about-young {
      position: absolute;
      right: 375px;
      top: 150px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .about-computer {
      position: absolute;
      right: 160px;
      top: 240px;
    }
    .about-colledge {
      position: absolute;
      right: 380px;
      top: 470px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    /*==============после желтого======================*/
    .about-text {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 725px;
      color: #666;
      width: 575px;
    }
    
    /*=============main section ==================*/
    
    
    
    
    
    /*===================footer================*/
    .page-footer {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: -80px;
      height: 80px;
    }
    /*============================ГРАДИЕНТ============================*/
    .page-footer {
      background: #bdc3c7;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
    }
    .copyright {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "RobotoRegular", sans-serif;
      line-height: 60px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .body:before {
      content: '';
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      width: 0;
      margin-top: 32767px;
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:1670px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1280px 100px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1650px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1250px 100px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1624px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1220px 100px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1593px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1195px 100px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1569px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 580px 80px, 1170px 100px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1544px){
    .content-section {
    background-position: bottom, 460px 80px, 1144px 100px;
    }
    .text-group {
    left: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1148px){
    .title {
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    .column {
      text-align: left;
      height: 267px;
      width:414px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 5px;
    
    }
    .textline {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 17px;
      height: 150px;
      width: 414px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .img-responsive {
      width: 414px;
      height: 267px;
    }
    .column10, .column9 {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    h3{
      font-size:26px;
      font-weight: 900;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    .clip {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    }
    .content-section:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      content: " ";
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
    }
    .content-section { display: inline-block; }
    /* start commented backslash hack \*/
    * html .content-section { height: 1%; }
    .content-section { display: block; }
    /* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="menu_li"><span class="surname">Heshimov</span><span class="next">notes</span></li>
     <li class="menu_li">Блог Васи</li>
     <a href="#"><li class="menu_right">Обо мне</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="menu_right">Книги</li></a>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
 <!---about me-->
  <div class="content-section">
   <div class="bg-color"></div>
    <div class="bio-content">
     <div class ="about-rh"></div>
      <div class="text-group">
       <h2 class="title">Насчет Рауфа</h2>
       <table id="family">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>Карьера:</td>
          <td>Baku electronics</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Cемейное<br>положение:</td>
          <td>Hе женат</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
      <h3 class="about-year">1989-<br><span>Родился<br>Сумгаит ,АЗЕ.</span></h3>
      <div class="about-timeline"></div>
      <h4 class="about-young"><strong>1996</strong><br>записывается в <br> Лицей "Истедад" на <br>имени Mухаммеда Физули </h4>
      <h4 class="about-computer"><strong>2004</strong><br>Познакомился с <br> компютерами</h4>
      <h4 class="about-colledge"><strong>2005</strong><br>Вступил в СГТК</h4>
 <!--mainsection-->
  <div class="about-text">
   <p>Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скорост
   Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скоростью.Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скоростью.Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скоростью.Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скоростью.Заработок верстальщика, во многом зависит от того как быстро он работает, думаю, это утверждение не нужно доказывать, все и так понятно. Поэтому, вполне логично, что многие, теми, или иными способами, пытаются себя ускорить, и сегодня я расскажу о Emmet –плагине для текстовых редакторов, который позволяет вбивать HTML и CSS c огромной скоростью.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 
 <footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
   <div class="copyright">Никакие права не зашишаются все права нарушаюится диким образом.© 2076 Heshimovnotes </div>
  </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: добавьте css стили к примеру, а то не совсем интересно играть в угадайку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас практически все блоки внутри `.wrapper` абсолютно позиционированы. Именно поэтому див не тянется. Задайте внутренним блокам `position:relative;` и тогда `.wrapper` будет тянуться.

В общем, это плохой тон - позиционировать все подряд дивы абсолютно. Такой шаблон будет не универсальным, его практически невозможно заполнять контентом и при этом не править каждый раз код. Такая верстка никогда не будет адаптивной.

Comment: https://www.gatesnotes.com/globalpages/bio     простите но тут тоже все элементы позиционированы абсолютно но все работает я хочу сделать что нибудь похожее

Comment: на мой взгляд совершенно не рационально, контент не поменять, с шириной не поиграть, пришлось страдать в адаптивизацию - обратите внимание на медиа тут КАЖДЫЙ элемент ровняли по пискелю! что то где-то дополнить на 2 строчки и все уже переравнивать надо, тоже самое и на флексах и на флоатах спокойно адаптивно сделать можно.

Answer (score 0):

Высота в процентах работает только в следующих случаях:

- Родитель имеет конкретную высоту или является окном браузера.
- Элемент имеет position absolute или fixed.
- Ещё есть несколько вариантов c flex'ами, но на них рассчитывать не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставил высоту главного контейнера (ну или боди) height:100vh; работает безотказно. А уж потом всем дочерних элементам можно свободно делать высоту в процентах.